# Passing variable to newly created tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I have a content script with an event that triggers a message to a "launching" script which I'm using to create a tab with a local html file and pass on the same message/variable to that tab. The tab should then load specified data based on the variable. It works as intended about 50% of the time, leading me to believe it's a synchronicity issue. I'm probably not going about this the right way, but it's the best I could work out on my own.

**Content Script (script.js):**

```
function openHistory(event) {
    var account = $(/*selector*/).html();
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(account);
}
```

**Launching Script (launch.js):**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(account) {
    chrome.tabs.create({url: 'background.html'}, function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, account);
    });
});
```

**HTML Script (background.js):**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(account) {
    loadPage(account);
});

function loadPage(account) {
    chrome.storage.sync.get(account, function(data) {
        // Do stuff with DOM
    });
}
```

**Manifest:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Extension",
    "version": "1.0",

    "permissions": ["storage", "tabs"],

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["launch.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },

    "content_scripts": [{
            "js": ["jquery.js", "script.js"]
    }]
}
```

**Update:** I added "alert(chrome.runtime.lastError.message)" inside of the callback for tabs.sendMessage in launch.js, and whenever it doesn't work, I get "Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist."

Comment: There's another simplier method which doesn't require message passing at all. That is by concatenating the data with the URL, in the query string or location fragment (aka location hash). E.g. `chrome.tabs.create({url: 'background.html#' + account});` (read using `location.hash.slice(1)`).

Comment: So simple! Thanks again, Rob. =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess would be that the callback used by `chrome.tabs.create` actually fires when the tab is ready, and not when its content has loaded. I can't quite tell because the [documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-create) for this method doesn't say when the callback is fired.

To get around this issue it may be best to have the newly opened background tab send a message back to its progenitor — as you know the launching script will already be up and running — to say "send me the details", at this point you then trigger `chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, account);`

If that makes sense?

The following has not been tested and is just a guess as to what could work. Obviously with a closer look it might be possible to use the `MessageSender` to work out if the message has come from the background script or not — rather than using an object property. However I prefer to be specific about these things with my own code:

**HTML Script (background.js):**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({from: 'background'});
```

**Launching Script (launch.js):**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(obj, sender) {
    if ( obj && obj.from == 'background' ) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(sender.tab.id, obj);
    }
    else {
        chrome.tabs.create({url: 'background.html' });
    }
});
```

Comment: Your observation is completely true. Instead of using `chrome.tabs.sendMessage`, I suggest to just use the `sendResponse` argument of the `onMessage` event, because it achieves the same result, and it's easier to use.

Comment: @RobW Nice point, I hadn't spotted that argument.. I'm not generally very chrome specific ;)

Comment: Brilliant solution, makes total sense. I'm just gonna go with Rob's location hash idea though on account of its utter simplicity. Should I still mark this as the correct answer? Not really sure what to do here... lol.

Comment: @Josh The answer explains why your code is not working, which is also very valuable. I would accept his answer.